# How to drag event to another calendar by tab menu in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, fullcalendar

I have a some calendars in tab container and switching by nav menu. And I would like drag event to another calendar by nav menu and when I dragging event and when nav menu switching I am losing event and getting error "Cannot read property 'isWithinClipping' of undefined". And when I returning to old tab I see event clone in the upper corner.
html:

```
<div id='container'>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">calendar 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">calendar 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
    <div id='source-calendar'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
    <div id='destination-calendar'></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

js code:

```
var srcCalendarEl = document.getElementById('source-calendar');
  var destCalendarEl = document.getElementById('destination-calendar');

  var srcCalendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(srcCalendarEl, {
    editable: true,
    droppable: true,
    initialDate: '2020-09-12',
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?overload-day',
    eventLeave: function(info) {
      console.log('event left!');
    }
  });

  var destCalendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(destCalendarEl, {
    initialDate: '2020-09-12',
    editable: true,
    droppable: true, // will let it receive events!
    eventReceive: function(info) {
      console.log('event received!');
    }
  });

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  srcCalendar.render();
  destCalendar.render();
});
  

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  srcCalendar.render();
  destCalendar.render();
});

$(".nav-link").on('mouseenter', function(e){
$(this).tab('show');
})
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bemulima/enfxsp75/23/)

So, any body tell me how to drag event to another calendar by tab menu in FullCalendar? Any ideas please.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because when a tab is opened, all the contents of the other tabs are made hidden - which, of course, includes the event you are trying to drag.

Comment: P.S. your JSFiddle doesn't reproduce the exact error you've mentioned, but it does show that the dragging isn't possible.

Comment: P.P.S. the word Calendar has one `l` in the middle. `Calendar`, not `Callendar`. Just like it's spelled inside `FullCalendar`, for example. I'm not sure why you have spelled it with 2 `l`s everywhere in your code and your question. All you have to do is take a look at a) the fullCalendar code in your own codebase, b) the fullCalendar website, c) the spelling of fullCalendar here in Stackoverflow, or d) just any online dictionary, to learn the correct spelling.

Comment: @ADyson (^_^) oh sorry, this is my carelessness. Now I'll remember for sure correct word calendar, thanks)

Comment: @ADyson about error "Cannot read property 'isWithinClipping' of undefined": I see in browser console. And I don't understand why jsfiddle not show error

Comment: Presumably, there's some difference between the fiddle and your original code. Of course, I can't tell you what that is because I can't see the original environment.

Comment: @ADyson, I noticed in ElementMirror class at getMirrorEl method writed code: `this.parentNode.appendChild(t)` I replaced to `document.body.appendChild(t)`.  Now event clone not lost when tab switched. But it also not worked not for long. I think the truth is somewhere near. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bemulima/enfxsp75/26/)

Answer (score 0):

So, I found solution for my task, for this I chainged source code of FullCalendar (it was so difficult).
Need to do for first the event mirror clone must create before document body in ElementMirror class at getMirrorEl method

```
ElementMirror.prototype.getMirrorEl = function () {
    var sourceElRect = this.sourceElRect;
    var mirrorEl = this.mirrorEl;
    if (!mirrorEl) {
        mirrorEl = this.mirrorEl = this.sourceEl.cloneNode(true); // cloneChildren=true
        // we don't want long taps or any mouse interaction causing selection/menus.
        // would use preventSelection(), but that prevents selectstart, causing problems.
        mirrorEl.classList.add('fc-unselectable');
        mirrorEl.classList.add('fc-dragging');
        applyStyle(mirrorEl, {
            position: 'fixed',
            zIndex: this.zIndex,
            visibility: '',
            boxSizing: 'border-box',
            width: sourceElRect.right - sourceElRect.left,
            height: sourceElRect.bottom - sourceElRect.top,
            right: 'auto',
            bottom: 'auto',
            margin: 0
        });
        //this.parentNode.appendChild(mirrorEl);
        document.body.appendChild(mirrorEl); // I don't no why not event clone realy create before body?
    }
    return mirrorEl;
}
```

For second: when event dragging to another calendar by tab menu fullCalendar rerendering for this reason HitDragging class getting new droppableStore list but not updating offsetTrackers list. For solution I just calling method this.prepareHits(); for update:

```
HitDragging.prototype.queryHitForOffset = function (offsetLeft, offsetTop) {
    this.prepareHits(); // for update offsetTrackers list
    var _a = this, droppableStore = _a.droppableStore, offsetTrackers = _a.offsetTrackers;
    var bestHit = null;
    for (var id in droppableStore) {
        var component = droppableStore[id].component;
        var offsetTracker = offsetTrackers[id];
        if (offsetTracker.isWithinClipping(offsetLeft, offsetTop)) {
            var originLeft = offsetTracker.computeLeft();
            var originTop = offsetTracker.computeTop();
            var positionLeft = offsetLeft - originLeft;
            var positionTop = offsetTop - originTop;
            var origRect = offsetTracker.origRect;
            var width = origRect.right - origRect.left;
            var height = origRect.bottom - origRect.top;
            if (
            // must be within the element's bounds
            positionLeft >= 0 && positionLeft < width &&
                positionTop >= 0 && positionTop < height) {
                var hit = component.queryHit(positionLeft, positionTop, width, height);
                console.log('hit', hit)
                if (hit &&
                    (
                    // make sure the hit is within activeRange, meaning it's not a deal cell
                    !component.props.dateProfile || // hack for DayTile
                        rangeContainsRange(component.props.dateProfile.activeRange, hit.dateSpan.range)) &&
                    (!bestHit || hit.layer > bestHit.layer)) {
                    // TODO: better way to re-orient rectangle
                    hit.rect.left += originLeft;
                    hit.rect.right += originLeft;
                    hit.rect.top += originTop;
                    hit.rect.bottom += originTop;
                    bestHit = hit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return bestHit;
};
```

Maybe it's not very good solution but it realy working. I hope FullCalendar's developers will add this feature.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bemulima/enfxsp75/27/)